How do get Facebook business ID after Facebook Login dialog?
I have used Facebook Login dialog with the correct permission and gotten access to a person's business accounts. I received a code after the login process and exchanged it using the /oauth/access_token endpoint to receive a system access token (which does not expire).
I now want to get the business IDs of the businesses that the person using the Facebook Login dialog gave me access to, so that I can link their business to mine using the "on behalf of" approach (I'm the partner, they are the client) .
However, for me to do that I require access to their business ID. How do I get that business ID? I know there is an API which returns all business IDs that I (the partenr) has access to, but I want the one that they just gave me access to using the Facebook Login dialog box. How can I do that?
